# Visual Studio 2019 color theming not working as it did in previous versions

Tags: visual-studio

I have to run multiple VS2019 instances under different user accounts, in order to debug my applications as different users.  In prior versions of VS (2017-prior), it was extremely helpful to have a different color theme for each user.  Setting a theme in VS as a particular user "stuck".  In other words, if I would exit an instance of VS run as user X, and then a week later launch VS as user X, it would come up with that color theme still in effect.  This was an easy way to tell at a glance, intuitively, what user an instance was running under.  (Note:  this is *not* the fonts/colors/syntax coloring in the editor.  This is the color of title bars/menus/borders/etc.)

With VS2019, changing the color theme (in Tools > Options > General > Visual Experience > Color Theme) in one instance of VS changes the theme for *all* open instances of VS, regardless of what user they were launched as.  Furthermore, if I log off and back on, color themes frequently reset to some other color.  The whole idea of a per-user color theme appears to no longer work.

Can VS2019 be configured to have the old, stable, per-user theme selection functionality?  If so, how?
Thank you.

Comment: When you say *different users*, do you mean different Windows log-on IDs or different Visual Studio (M/S) accounts? If the former, are all your Win logons using the same M/S account?

Comment: This would be better served using Microsoft's Feedback system. Click the "Send Feedback" button in the upper right and select "Report a Problem".

Comment: @Casey Possibly. However, there *may* be a quick fix (that I can post). Just waiting for clarification from the OP.

Comment: These are different Windows log-on IDs.  I will try Microsoft's feedback system.  Thanks.

Comment: @user3511585 Do you sign on to a Visual Studio account? The same one in each log-on? If so, you can disable synchronization of settings. I can post an answer showing how to do that...

Comment: Oh, yes I do sign into a VS account.  And yes, the same on each log-on.

Comment: Tried clicking on my avatar in VS2019 upper right, Account Settings > Account Options > Environment > Accounts > Synchronize Visual Studio setting across devices < unchecked it.  But then changing the color theme in one VS instance still changes the theme in every open instance.  Do I need to restart VS2019 for that setting change to take effect?

Comment: @user3511585 You'll need to disable that synchronization in *every* login (they're all considered separate 'devices', I guess) and (probably) restart each one. Repetition may be required. I've had similar issues with font sizes on two different desktops ... it took quite a bit of perseverance to get it to take effect. Or just change the setting and exit (no restart) in each one, until all are done.